# change url into hash fragment variant

Tags: ajax, url, uri

It doesnt look like simple hashing pushState since its really changing the whole url.

There is no page-refresh + it is totaly changing the url by cutting it all off and pushing it to the url again as a hash fragment. Please checkout the example below.

visit for example the url:
http://www.couverts.nl/restaurant/13233/jo-van-den-bosch/den-bosch

which instantly gets changed to:
http://www.couverts.nl/#/restaurant/13233/jo-van-den-bosch/den-bosch

Anyone know the techinque used here? And maybe someone can give a simple example of how to implement it.

Comment: Have you tried either looking at the page source, or googling this? In any case, don't do this, it's terrible.

Comment: Also, see this: http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/specification.html

Comment: @Marcin solution using purely `replaceState` aren't terrible at all: https://github.com/blog/760-the-tree-slider - the fragment can be terrible indeed!

Comment: @greut: Right, the problem is using these fragment urls to make your whole site.

Comment: marcin, i have been inspecting the source and putting breakpoints for like 3 hours. Then i have googled it but didnt find any relevant articles. So, thats why i tried it here.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the URL with no page refresh uses the very new history API, mostly [history.replaceState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#The_replaceState%28%29.C2.A0method)

Benjamin Balupton has written the very good [history.js](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js)

And I invite your to check the whole specifications too: http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/history.html

Changing only the `location.hash` is the easy part here.

Comment: greut, i guess it hasnt anything to do with the new history api since the above mentioned example also works in IE7,8 and 9. I have no clue how they achieve it

Comment: afaik, IE7 cannot change the URL without reloading the page so it's not working the same way.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also looking close to this issue: what about Apache rewrite directives? A quick and dirty one would be:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/#/$1
```

and then `index.php` reads the path do some work and simply sends a header to client

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/#/bla/bla')
```

The whole idea behind this is of course AJAX and the Front Controller pattern.

PS: I've just rewritten some Apache directives from "Directing All Requests to index.php" of Chapter 2 related with the Zend_Controller class from the book "Practical Web 2.0 Applications with PHP" by Quentin Zervaas...